# Install Scandit fail. The package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, barcode

I am trying to install nuget package "Scandit" to my project.

IDE: Visual studio Mac(Xamarin.Forms 4.6.0.726)

The following is the error message.

```
Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'Scandit.BarcodePicker.Xamarin.5.14.5.10' with respect to project 'Modbusbutton3', targeting '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile78'
CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/scandit.barcodepicker.xamarin/index.json
Total number of results gathered : 52
Gathering dependency information took 217.67 ms
Summary of time taken to gather dependencies per source :
https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json - 5.27 ms
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'Scandit.BarcodePicker.Xamarin.5.14.5.10' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
Resolving actions to install package 'Scandit.BarcodePicker.Xamarin.5.14.5.10'
Resolved actions to install package 'Scandit.BarcodePicker.Xamarin.5.14.5.10'
Found package 'Scandit.BarcodePicker.Xamarin 5.14.5.10' in '/Users/dej.pvi/Downloads/20200506-WiFi Solution for iOS/packages'.
For adding package 'Scandit.BarcodePicker.Xamarin.5.14.5.10' to project 'Modbusbutton3' that targets 'portable45-net45+win8+wp8'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'Scandit.BarcodePicker.Xamarin.5.14.5.10' does not exist in project 'Modbusbutton3'
Executing nuget actions took 15.64 ms
Could not install package 'Scandit.BarcodePicker.Xamarin 5.14.5.10'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile78', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

Can any one help how to solve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As I checked Scandit.BarcodePicker [github sample](https://github.com/Scandit/barcodescanner-sdk-xamarin-samples/tree/release-5.15/Unified/ExtendedSample) they are using two different packages.

**Scandit.BarcodePicker.Xamarin**

This package is installed only in Android and iOS project.

[image]
**Scandit.BarcodePicker.Unified**

This package is installed in every project.

[image]

According to your log Target Framework of your project is PCL. You might consider to convert you project to .NETStandard 2.0, because this might be other issue why you are not able to install this package. Check the [link here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-tip-easiest-way-to-convert-a-pcl-project-to-net-standard-projec/).